# Overwrite sweeper bot transaction with higher gas price

Tags: transactions, gas, nonce, bot, sweeping

Is it possible to beat sweeper bot transactions by creating a tx with the same nonce but higher gas price?

From what i understand, block builders are incentivized to pick tx with higher gas fees.
Therefore from a set of transactions with the same nonce, the transaction with the highest gas price would be picked.

I have tried beating the bots on my hacked wallet, with that strategy, but the bots transaction always gets included in the block.

Am i missing something? Are there other factors that made the bot transactions to beat mine?

Comment: Even if you increase your transaction's gas price to outbid the sweeper bot, it might still win due to factors like network congestion or its sophisticated programming. Miners may have their own criteria for selecting transactions, and if the block is full, even high-priced transactions can get delayed. This shows that transaction prioritization is not just about gas prices but also involves various technical and strategic considerations in the blockchain ecosystem.

Comment: I see.. do you know if it is possible to listen to internal transactions? I beat the bots by using internal transactions, but i'm just curious whether it is actually possible to listen to internal transactions. @DevCrypto

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved my issue by funding my wallet via internal transactions.
i.e making the transfer in smart contract logic.

I followed the suggestion in this metamask post:
https://support.metamask.io/hc/en-us/articles/5716855323675-Fighting-back-against-sweeper-bots

specifically in the section:
"Using a self-destructing smart contract"

The smart contract would deploy, transfer the funds, and selfdestruct in 1 tx.

Subsequently, execute the transaction you require using your compromised wallet.

Notes: If your second tx still responded with not enough funds, perhaps wait for 1-2 seconds. before executing the tx.
I was using geth and i had to wait 2 secs after the first tx was mined, perhaps my node have not synced yet.

i'm not sure if bots can not listen to internal transactions, or if its just the sweeper bots on my wallet don't.

but i think this method is worth the try.

Be safe folks